# How to get multiple input in one line in c#

Tags: c#, input

c# code, I can"t solve this:

```
    int a, b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
   
    Console.ReadLine();
```

anyone help me.

Comment: Why do you want to? Just do it on two lines.

Comment: if you have many inputs, use a loop + an array/list

Comment: If you want the user to input multiple values in one line, you have to split it manually: `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))`

Comment: Why the constraint of doing it in one line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample:

```
(int a,int  b) = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Comment: @PaulF Doesn't that depend on what OP means by "in one line"? I interpreted it to mean a single line of code. Despite being a bit of an abuse of `ValueTuple`, Hamed's answer achieves this.

Comment: @Llama - a badly worded question, open to interpretation

Comment: @PaulF Indeed it is.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to euhm, misuse Linq to do it in one line. But seriously, just use a few lines.

```
(int? a, int? b) = 
Console
.ReadLine()
.Split(' ')
.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
.Aggregate(((int?)null, (int?)null), (l, next) => l.Item1 == null ? (next, (int?)null) : (l.Item1, next));
```

Read the input and split it:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
var parts = input.Split(' ');
int a = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
int b = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
```